# newline in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, log

needing to check every hour a logfile looking for "unable to connect to the ldap", I've put in cron hourly this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
> result
cat logfile.log | grep -a 'unable to connect to the ldap' > result
if [ -s result ]
then
 echo -e "Attention! Missing ldap connection at " "\n" `cut -c-24 result`
fi
exit 0
```

It does its job, just the format is horrible, being something like:

```
Attention! Missing ldap connection at
2022-05-25 20:35:53,293 2022-05-25 20:35:53,294 2022-05-25 20:35:53,295 2022-05-25 20:35:53,295
```

Is there a way to have it formatted as here above?

```
Attention! Missing ldap connection at  
2022-05-25 20:35:53,293
2022-05-25 20:35:53,294
2022-05-25 20:35:53,295
2022-05-25 20:35:53,295
```

Adding a "\n" inside and outside the cut statement is useless.

Thanks,

Sil

Comment: `printf 'Attention! Missing ldap connection at %s\n' "$(cut -c-24 result)"` however there are likely much cleaner methods of processing the result than saving to and cutting from a file - if you want suggestions, please add a snippet of the log

Comment: Thanks! I've cutted first 24 characters of each "grepped" log line because logs are something horrible (Shibboleth IdP's logs) and I just wanted to be informed about failure datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Add this filter to your output  `grep -Eo "[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*,[0-9]*"`.
So how does this work

- `grep -Eo` ok, so the `E` is extended regex for grep and the `o` show only nonempty parts of lines that match
- "[0-9]*" prints all number from 0 to 9 and continues until something that is not 0 to 9
- the rest is just matching characters

Answer (score 0):

Based on the initial lines in the Q:

```
 echo -e "Attention! Missing ldap connection at\n $(cut -c-24 result)"
```

... maybe?

***Not** tested in any live situation*